# How about many "require_once" will affect the page load speed?

Tags: functions

In the `functions.php` I pretty much use the function `require_once` to call about 30 files in my wordpress theme. (30 times use `require_once`)

How about that will affect the page load speed?

Have there any way to more optimally?

Comment: As written, this is a pure PHP question. `require_once` works the same in WordPress as in any PHP application.

Comment: I know it, but I want to know about that will affect the page load speed :( Thanks you!

Comment: You've missed the point. Pure PHP questions are off topic per the [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it has not a significant impact unless you got... let's say one hundred of them in the same file which I really doubt. Indeed there is more work but it's not enough to put your performance down.

I think you'd better optimize wp queries